# What may be causing the "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in views\contact-form.ejs while compiling ejs" error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I have read through a ton of posts related to this error, but none seem to involve EJS. I am admittedly very green when it comes to EJS (and JS in general), so it won't shock me if the fix is something simple and obvious to more seasoned devs.

I have a snippet of EJS in my contact-form.ejs file to pass validation errors in the form of flash messages to the page when the user does not fill in the form correctly or completely. However, my syntax throws the above error when I attempt to navigate to the contact form page.

I've been looking at it for 2 days and made several feeble attempts at troubleshooting. Here is the code in question:

```
<%- messages('message', locals) %>

<% if (errors !== undefined) { %>
    // Output the errors to the page
    <% errors.forEach(function(error) { %>
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <%= ${error.message} %>
        </div>
    <% }) %>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're mixing up templating languages. Try to remove `${}` around `error.message` on the 7th line, like:

```
<%- messages('message', locals) %>

<% if (errors !== undefined) { %>
    // Output the errors to the page
    <% errors.forEach(function(error) { %>
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <%= error.message %>
        </div>
    <% }) %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Yup. That was it. Makes sense because I was trying to convert some of this over from Pug. Thanks!